# What is the default value for C++ class members

Tags: c++, class, struct, default-value

What is the default values for members of a struct and members of a class in c++, and how do these rules differ (e.g. between classes/structs/primitives/etc) ? Are there circumstances where the rules about the default values differs ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializati, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/c-does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are no differences between structs and classes in this regard in C++. They all are called just *class types*.

Members of class types have no default values in general case. In order to for a class member to get a deterministic value it has to be *initialized*, which can be done by

- Default constructor of the member itself
- Constructor initializer list of the enclosing class
- Explicitly specified initializer for object of the enclosing class (that includes value-initialization and initialization with aggregate initializer).

Additionally, all objects with static storage duration are zero-initialized at the program startup.

Aside from the above cases, class members, once again, have no default values and will initially contain unpredictable garbage values.

Comment: If static storage is zero-initialized would depend on the operating system you're running.

Comment: @jpyllman: No. Static storage is always zero-initialized. It is guaranteed (required) by the language, regardless of any operating systems.

Comment: OK, I've tried to find such info but not finding it. I've always assumed it is undefined unless you set some value.

Comment: @jpyllman It's part of the C standard (not C++). It's mentioned in K&R.

Comment: @lorean: I'm not sure what you mean by "not C++". Unconditional zero-initialization for objects with static storage duration is explicitly present in C++ standard as well. C++ is different from C since it allows dynamic (i.e. run-time) initialization of static objects, but still C++ says that all static objects are zero-initialized before any other initialization begins.

Comment: My comment was poorly worded. I meant that it's specified in a part of the C standard which was inherited by C++.

Comment: If @[HansPassant's exception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2614832/1995714) is true, I think it should probably be added to this more complete answer.

Comment: @cp.engr: Hans's code uses an explicitly specified initializer - `()` - which either invokes constructor of enclosing class `someClass` or triggers value-initialization of the new object. Both cases are covered by the above list.

Comment: Since C++14 static objects are not necessarily zero-initialized first, [see detail](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization).

Comment: @AnT If I am not mistaken, default constructor is implicitly called if there are no user defined constructors. So how can we initialize using default constructor as you said above? That means can we instantiate object with default constructor and without default constructor?

Answer (score 17):

Yeah, there is one.  If you initialize an object with the default constructor and use parentheses then the POD members will be zero initialized:

```
someClass * p = new someClass();
```

Comment: This statement is not true. It is very dependent on who wrote the compiler. There is nothing in the standard that says a POD value will be initialised to anything unless the programmer assigned a value to it. This is why developer tools such as valgrind exist.

Comment: @DamianDixon Nope, see following: `C++14 8.5 11` *"An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized."*. `8.5 8` *"To value-initialize an object of type T means: ... if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then
the object is zero-initialized ..."* `8.5 6` *"To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means: ... — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class
subobject is zero-initialized ..."*

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, You have to however use an empty parentheses. If you do not add (), i.e. provide some sort of initialisation then you don't get this behaviour and you end up with an an uninitialised POD. So the programmer has to do something to initialise the variable.

Comment: @DamianDixon Yes, that's the point! I've posted the first comment because you seemed to disagree with the fact that `()` zero-inits class fields in abscence of user-defined ctor, which is what Hans Passant said.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, point taken. I had not run into this change in the language before. I tend to always initialise variables to a defined value by habit as I have to use VS2010 and upwards. I've updated my answer to reflect this change in the standard.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I have had a play with using empty parenthesis and personally I would avoid the use of them. Please see the examples in my answer as to why (not enough space here). Hopefully I now understand this bit a bit better. Thanks

Comment: Presumably ```someClass p = someClass();``` has the same effect?