# Are default constructors called automatically for member variables?

Tags: c++, constructor, header

Say I have this class:

```
//Awesome.h
class Awesome
{
    public:
        Awesome();
    private:
        membertype member;
}

//Awesome.cpp
#include "Awesome.h"

Awesome::Awesome()
:member()
{
}
```

If I omit the `member()` in the initialization list of the constructor of `Awesome`, will the constructor of `member` be called automatically? And is it only called when I don't include `member` in the initialization list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default value for C++ class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614809/what-is-the-default-value-for-c-class-members)

Comment: depends on `membertype` but usually yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From § 8.5

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with
>   automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note:
>   objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized,
>   see 3.6.2. —end note ]

**Update for future references**: Further the meaning of default initialized is defined as

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>  — *if T is a
>   (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor
>   for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no
>   accessible default constructor)*;
>  — if T is an array type, each
>   element is default-initialized;
>  — otherwise, no initialization is
>   performed.
>  If a program calls for the default initialization of
>   an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a
>   user-provided default constructor.

Further it varies from value initialized referring this:-

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>  — if T is a
>   (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided
>   constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and
>   the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>  — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class
>   type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is
>   zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor
>   is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
>  — if T is an array
>   type, then each element is value-initialized;
>  — otherwise, the
>   object is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 23):

Yes. When a variable is not given in the initializer list, then it is default constructed automatically.

*Default construction* means, that if `membertype` is a `class` or `struct`, then it will be default constructed, if it's a built-in array, then each element will be default constructed and if it's a build-in type, then **no initialization** will be performed (unless the `Awesome` object has static or thread-local storage duration). The last case means that the member variable can (and often will) contain unpredictable garbage in case the `Awesome` object is created on the stack or allocated on the heap.