# c++ float passed as argument not printed correctly

Tags: c++

I'm really new to c++. I have a simple console application with an `header.h` that holds my class

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    float x, y, z;

    MyClass(float x, float y, float z);
};
```

I have a `implement.cpp` with all my implemented methods and I have

```
MyClass::MyClass(float x, float y, float z) {};
```

Then in `main.cpp` I try to simply print the values

```
int main()
{
  MyClass One(-3.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);

  cout <<  "Firsth Object: " << One.x << ", " << One.y << ", " << One.z << endl;
}
```

But in console values are printed like :

-1.07374e+08, -1.07374e+08, -1.07374e+08

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the use of your constructor?

Comment: You shouldn't call your files "header.h" and "implement.cpp", but rather "MyClass.h" and "MyClass.cpp"

Comment: @MarkusWeninger: That's only true if you have opted for a one-to-one mapping of class and header/source pair, which is not always the case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are right, but for this case, where a 1:1 mapping exists between header and implementation, I prefer using the same file name.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger: You don't know that a 1:1 mapping has been chosen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Right, right, I read the question again and have to admit that it really does not point out that it's a 1:1 relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor did not initialize any of the members: `MyClass::x`, `MyClass::y` nor `MyClass::z`.

You must do:

```
MyClass::MyClass(float x, float y, float z)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
};
```

or better yet (more idiomatic, and possibly faster):

```
MyClass::MyClass(float x, float y, float z) : 
    x( x ), y( y ), z( z )
{
};
```

Without that, you're printing the values of uninitialized members of the `MyClass` object `One`. In general, you must [always initialize members of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614809/what-is-the-default-value-for-c-class-members) before you can use them.

Comment: Turn MyClass::MyClass(float x, float y, float z) {}; into MyClass::MyClass(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {};

Comment: Really thank you. As I said, I'm really a beginner. What is the meaning of this-> ?

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to use different names for the parameters in an initializer list and variable beginning with `_` are reserved by the standards spec.

Comment: It is not necessary to rename arguments with a `_` prefix, compiler is smart enough in this case to distinct class members and function arguments.

Comment: @Galik: I know, but I'm always scared about using the same names.....I prefer to avoid any kind of ambiguity.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I totally just imposed the same variable names on your answer then. I agree with Galik and Victor, it's completely unnecessary and hurts readability. But if you insist on mangling names, why not mangle the private members, instead of the formal arguments?

Comment: @CodyGray: No problem and thanks for the help and the added link!

Comment: @jpo38 If you think about it it is actually always safer to use the same names, less chance you get the variables in the wrong order because they always look visually identical - mistakes look more obvious. That's how I see it :)

Comment: @Koosshh56: In case you're also a StackOverflow beginner, don't forget to accept an answer on this page! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your current constructor does nothing.

You have to initialize your objects variable. For this you can use

```
MyClass::MyClass(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) 
{
}
```

This type of initialization in constructors is called *initializer list*, you can read it up [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

This has the same effect as the constructor pointed out by @jpo38.

Comment: This answer duplicates another with just a little correction. It is worth just to add a comment to the `jpo38`'s answer.

Comment: Okay, so should I delete the answer? I'm pretty new to writing ansers on SO.

Comment: I think yes, because people should usually add answers which have a significant difference. If you just have a correction of another answer - just add a comment to it, there is no need in duplicating answers.

Comment: But I think that this _has_ a significant difference, because most other languages don't have a construct like _initializer list_. I came from C# and Java and was suprised that something like this is possible.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: It _is_ a significant difference.