# in C++, what would the the value of data-members be in class if we did not initialize them in constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

My quesitions is about the class data-members initializations. I would like to know the Initialization rules, such as the build-in type (int, double ,float) and user-defined type. If we didn't initialize them, the content of them is undefined or the default constructor will be used?

Comment: It depends. It depends on a lot of things. It depends on so many things that I always tell people, "If in doubt, just initialize everything yourself."

Comment: Do you mean you have a user provided constructor, but you don't explicitly initialize the data members?

Comment: You may look at [default_initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) and [value_initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Initializing bases and members

Initialization of non-static data members is described in C++11 standard **12.6.2 Initializing bases and members**:

> ... if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated
>   by a mem-initializer-id ..., then
>
> - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a    brace-or-equal-initializer, the entity is initialized as specified in
>     8.5;
> - otherwise, if the entity is a variant member (9.5), no    initialization is performed;
> - otherwise, the entity is default-initialized (8.5).
>
> After the call
>   to a constructor for class X has completed, if a member of X is **neither
>   initialized nor given a value** during
>   execution of the *compound-statement* of the body of the constructor,
>   the member has **indeterminate value**.

Note: If an object is *default initialized* and the object is not a class nor array type, no initialization is performed (see 8.5.6).

**Example**:

```
struct A {
    A();
};

struct B {
    B(int);
};

struct C {
    C() { }     // initializes members as follows:
    A a;        // OK: calls A::A()
    const B b;  // error: B has no default constructor
    int i;      // OK: i has indeterminate value
    int j = 5;  // OK: j has the value 5
};
```

### Objects with static storage duration

Variables with static storage duration are zero initialized (**3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables**):

> Non-local variables with static storage duration are initialized as a
>   consequence of program initiation. ...
>
> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) ...
>   shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other
>   initialization takes place.

### User defined types

For user defined types a default constructor is called (if not called explicitly another constructor, see example above). If the constructor is implicitly declared (generated by compiler) the members are initialized according to **Initializing bases and members** (see above). If the constructor is user defined it's user's responsibility to initialize class members.

Comment: Does the default constructor really initialize its members?

Comment: @nickyC It depends. You can write it or not. I don't say it initializes them.

Comment: A user defined type can also be a POD. Also, the POD terminology is pre-C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right, it was C++03. I've updated it for C++11. I hope more todays C++ users will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default init of class non static members c++ classes.
Once the memory for the object is allocated, the values of the members hold whatever was in the allocated memory. You can think of it as of "random bits" or "garbage".

See [What is the default value for C++ class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614809/what-is-the-default-value-for-c-class-members)