# Constructors for variable types

Tags: c++

This is a very basic question but for declaration of variables are constructors called?

```
int x; //Global variable

class A{
public:
int y; 
A()

}
```

Comment: A constructor is only called, when you instantiate an object.

Comment: `A()` is not proper syntax. If this is supposed to be a constructor declaration there is a `;` missing at the end. If it is supposed to be a constructor definition it should be followed by `{ /* definition body */ }`. A semicolon is also missing at the end of the class definition.

Comment: For the global variable, the constructor is not called?

Comment: `int` is a *Plain Old Data* (POD) type. It doesn't have a constructor but instead follows rules about initialization.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question. Are you asking what values `x` and `y` might end up with if you create an `A`? If so, there are clues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402. IIf not, what are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it commented out, `int` is a **POD (Plain Old Data)** type.

> A Plain Old Data Structure in C++ is an aggregate class that contains
>   only PODS as members, has no user-defined destructor, no user-defined
>   copy assignment operator, and no nonstatic members of
>   pointer-to-member type

Note that, a constructor is nothing but a member function. A member function must belong to a class and as we mentioned, `int` is just a built-in fundamental variable type, **not a class**. So to answer your question, there is no constructor called for the declaration of non-class types such as primitive data types, array types, pointer types and so on.

However, it may cause a misunderstood to see an initialization like this;

```
int var(10);
```

Even though it looks and acts so similar to a constructor, there is no constructor called there. It is just an initialization. `int var(10);`  simply equals to `int var = 10;`.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand that the built-in types don't *have* constructors; this is a privilege reserved for user-defined types (classes).

What you're really asking is whether a data member of type `int` will be zero-initialised by default, and the answer is [*no*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614902/560648); they're "default-initialized", which leaves them with an unspecified value that cannot read.

You should initialize `y` yourself in the class constructor `A()` — that's what it's for! Assuming you wanted it to be zero:

```
class A
{
public:
   int y; 
   A() : y(0) {}
};
```

Global variables are a bit different. What I wrote above is still basicaly true for those, but since they have static storage duration there is an "extra" step which makes all their bits zero before your program starts. This has the effect of making `x` initialised to zero despite the lack of explicit initializer, and you can rely on this.

The chapter about variable initialisation in your C++ book will go into greater detail about this.

Comment: Arent zero initialisation and default initialisation the same? Do you mean value initialisation?

Comment: @user10713170 No, they aren't, and no, I don't. Further reading: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/initialization-is-bonkers/

Comment: Printing y does not give me an indeterminate value? It gives me 0...

Comment: @user10713170 Printing `y` gives your program undefined behaviour because, yes, it has an indeterminate value. Seeing `0` is one such outcome of that. Don't assume that because you see a nice neat number like `0` that everything is okay. "Indeterminate" does not mean "a large number without visual base-10 patterns, like 1433728", it means "indeterminate"