# What will cause the data members in class initialized to zeros?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Default constructor shouldn't zero out any data member. But in some situation, it seems not to be like this.

The code example is brief.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  int val;
  Foo() = default;
};

int main() {
  Foo bar;
  if (bar.val != 0) {
    cout << "true" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "false" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As excepted, above program outputs:

```
true
```

However, if a print statement for bar's data member added, the `var` member will be initialized to zero:

```
...
int main() {
  Foo bar;
  cout << bar.val << endl;
  ...
}
```

The outputs will be:

```
0
false
```

Similarly, if adding virtual function and destructor to the class `Foo`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  virtual void Print() {}
  ~Foo() {}
  int val;
  Foo() = default;
};

int main() {
  Foo bar;
  if (bar.val != 0) {
    cout << "true" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "false" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

or just init bar object:

```
class Foo {
public:
  int val;
  Foo() = default;
};

int main() {
  Foo bar = Foo();
  ...
}
```

outputs with:

```
false
```

So what‘s the cause that influence the data member value of class? Shouldn't all of this test outputs with `true`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the default value for C++ class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614809/what-is-the-default-value-for-c-class-members)

Comment: The section on [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) explains some of the cases where you can count on zeros.

Comment: Note that reading an uninitialised variable is Undefined Behaviour and causes the entire program to have no well defined meaning. The compiler is allowed to do *anything* to *any* part of your program when it contains UB. You can no longer reason about it.

Comment: Maybe there is no reason for this situation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) in this case:

> otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

Note that indeterminate value includes `0`, which is a valid result too. BTW reading these indeterminate values leads to UB.

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if it also pointed out that a subsequent reading of an undetermined value [causes UB in C++](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#indet-2).

Comment: But why init with `0` for some specific situation? Is there some reason?

Comment: @yeah Reasoning about undefined behavior makes no sense.