# Difference between these two constructor calls

Tags: c++, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

I believe this question was already asked, but I cannot find it with a quick search.

```
Foo ob* = new Foo; 

Foo ob* = new Foo();
```

Is there a difference between these two ways of creating an object in C++? If not then is one of these considered a bad practice? Does every compiler treats it the same?

Comment: There is a subtle difference between using parentheses and not using parentheses, and a really detailed explanation is offered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Comment: @birryree: Ah, there it is :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/c-does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types

Answer (score 7):

The first is *default initialization*, the second is *value initialization*. If `Foo` is of class type, they both invoke the default constructor. If `Foo` is fundamental (e.g. `typedef int Foo;`), default initialization performs no initialization, while value-initialization performs zero-initialization.

For class types and arrays, the initialization proceeds recursively to the members/elements in the expected way.

Comment: Your answer is so much more accurate than mine, dammit

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, other than the fact that if `Foo` is a built-in type [then the former does not value-initialise it](http://codepad.org/V4sAN45m).

So:

```
new int;   // unspecified value
new int(); // 0
```

This matches up nicely with "normal" allocation for built-ins, too:

```
int x;     // unspecified value
int x = 0; // well, you can't do `int x()`, but, if you could...
```

Comment: You can do `int x{};` nowadays :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Good point ;) Doesn't really help me make a comparison with something "familiar" though!

Comment: Hehe, no. I think last time we concluded that the best you can do for automatic objects is `int x((int());` or so.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Lol yes, was just playing with that and decided not to bother any further ;)