# How to always initialize properly?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, value-initialization, aggregate-initialization

With C++11 the *Unified Initialization* has been introduced and I got the impression that `{}` is now a quite safe [initialization](http://iap.cs.tamu.edu/IAP_Initializers) for all cases (when allowed). But I [just noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418195/472245), that I mistaken.

**What *is* a safe form of initialization for all types?** Baring classes with deleted/private default c'tor, or course.

### Details for some type-kinds

Here is a **built-in**:

```
int u;          // evil, x will be un-initialized
int v{};        // nice value-initialization, as far as I know.
int w={};       // nice value-initialization, right?
int x={0};      // proper initialization, not suited for other types though
int x=0;        // proper initialization, also not suited
```

But with an **aggregate** like `tm`

```
#include <ctime>
tm birth1{};    // evil. nothing initialized.
tm birth4=tm(); // yes! nice value-initialization.
tm birth2 ={};  // evil. nothing initialized
tm birth3 ={0}; // evil, only first member init
```

but with *C-arrays*

```
int data1[9] ={};  // evil. nothing initialized.
int data1[9] ={0}; // proper (value?)-initialization of all elements
```

And what with **classes** beyond aggregates with a compiler-generated default-c'tor?

```
struct Widget {
    std::string name;
    int val;
};
Widget w1;    // w1.val will be uninitialized
Widget w2{};  // w2.val will be uninitialized
Widget w3 = Widget{}; // ??? will w3.val be value-initialized?
Widget w4{0}; // an error, or course.
```

Did I forget an important kind?

### A template that works for all?

As an extended question I wonder if there is a proper/good/any way to write a template function that returns a properly initialized object for all types that can be initialized in that way:

```
template<typename T>
T init() {
    return T{};
    // or 'T t = T{}; return t;'
    // or...
}
```

Comment: [dcl.init.aggr]/7 (from n3485) "If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member
not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list" (i.e. value-initialized).

Comment: I think there's also been a defect, `Widget w2{};` will zero-initialize `w2` (and then call a non-trivial default-ctor).

Comment: [boost::value_init](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm)

Comment: See [CWG 1301](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301) and the related (linked) defects. Summing up my comments: As far as I know, after the defects have been fixed, `{}` will "properly" initialize an object/value.

Comment: Be aware that VS2013 does not implement the resolution to CWG 1301, continuing Visual C++'s long tradition of failing to correctly value-initialize. On an unrelated note, if you are paranoid about failing to initialize you should take a look at [AAA-style](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Comment: Maybe I should say that first I am interested in the *standard*s way to do it. Only second I am considering implementations -- those can be fixed. (Am I an romantic optimist?)