# Why is it that string s; will always result in an empty string?

Tags: c++

According to many references, when you write Myclass C; it wil use the default ctor, which does not do any initialization and so should leave C's members as garbage. So why is it that STL classes are value-initialized ?

Comment: Who says the default constructor should leave the object uninitialized? That would make it unusable, wouldn't it?

Comment: For example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types

Comment: `string` is not a built-in type.

Comment: Either many references are wrong, or you misread them.

Comment: The first answer in the link you posted answers it.

Comment: It is not  a built-in type, but as I understand the default ctor will recursively call default ctors of subobjects until we reach basic types such as int which will be left underminate

Comment: The first answer says that C c; // Compiler-provided default constructor is used
// Here `c.x` contains garbage which is inconsitant with the fact that string s; contain well determined value

Comment: Because `std::string` performs some intializations in its default constructor implementation?

Comment: `string`'s default constructor creates an empty string. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `MyClass C;` the compiler generates code that calls the default constructor for your class `MyClass`. The "default constructor" is the constructor that can be called with no arguments, and the effect of calling it is whatever that constructor does. If you leave it up to the compiler to generate the default constructor, then, yes, members that have builtin types don't get initialized. If you write your own default constructor you can initialize whichever members you think appropriate. That's what `std::string` does: it sets up the string object so that it holds an empty string.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : member(3) {} // default constructor
    int member;
};

MyClass C; // C.member has the value 3
```

Comment: I thought default constructor meant "compiler generated constructor". Hence the reason for my confusion.