# overflow when attempting to push_back randomly generated numbers in a vector

Tags: c++

my code is shown here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

struct funcs
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    int sum;
    void createVectorValues(){
        while(values.size() < 100)
        {
            int x = rand() % 100;
            values.push_back(x);
        }
        for(int& a : values)
        {
            sum += 1;
        }
        cout << sum;

    }
};
int main()
{
    srand;
    funcs myFunct;
    myFunct.createVectorValues();
    
}
```

the following code results in a large value such as -858993360

How can I change this code so that it can function properly

Comment: _`&funcs::createVectorValues;`_ I am afraid this statement doesn't do what you think it does.  Can you elaborate about what you thought please.?

Comment: You need to create a `funcs` object then call the function: `funcs f; f.createVectorValues();`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp calling `srand()` once at the beginning of `main ()` would also be a good idea.

Comment: Bah. `rand` is for pansies. The cool kids all use `std::uniform_int_distribution` from the [<random> library.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)

Comment: [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) could come in handy.

Comment: 1) `sum` is not initialized, it's value is indeterminated and incrementing it is pointless. 2) What do you *really* want to sum?

Comment: `srand;` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't define a constructor for `funcs`, so you get the default constructor, which invokes the default constructor of each member.  This means the `int` member `sum` is left with an indeterminate value.  See [Does the default constructor initialize built-in types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types).  You probably want to write a constructor that initializes `sum` to `0`.
2. `srand;` isn't a function call.  It's valid syntax, because `srand` evaluates to a pointer to the `srand` function, but it's an expression with no side effects, so it does nothing.  Much as if you had written `3;`.  To call the function, you need `srand(arg)`, where `arg` is an appropriate integer.  Or, switch to the [C++11 random number generation features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), which are much more powerful and usually have better randomness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main(int, char **) {
    funcs myFunct;
    myFunct.createVectorValues();
}
```

Although no idea why your antivirus is involved. That might be a separate issue.

Comment: There's no "try", either your answer solves the OPs problem or not.

Comment: Well, given that I don't know a thing about his antivirus system -- and he didn't talk about it -- I guess I could have skipped giving him a solution that at least would get him closer.